# Weird spacing between SVG and main content

Tags: html, css, svg

### Problem

I have the following code and I don't understand why there's a space between `section:before` and `section`:

```css
section {
    background-color: #E9F6FF;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}

section:before,
section:after {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

section:before {
    content: url(https://svgshare.com/i/NSF.svg);
}

section:after {
    content: url(https://svgshare.com/i/NRP.svg);
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

### What I tried

I tried to check if the SVG had a viewport that was bigger than the shape itself.

I've also tried to remove margins and paddings on all elements.

### Question

Why is there that space? How can I remove it?

Comment: I have reproduced in chrome, I don't find any spacing between svg and the main content

Comment: it seems a part of the SVG itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like space reserved for the descenders. If I add `font-size:0` then it closes the gap:

```css
section {
    background-color: #E9F6FF;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
}

section:before,
section:after {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-size:0;
}

section:before {
    content: url(https://svgshare.com/i/NSF.svg);
}

section:after {
    content: url(https://svgshare.com/i/NRP.svg);
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```